# Installing package from github with pip - error

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install the GPdoemd package (https://github.com/cog-imperial/GPdoemd) in a virtuel environment but when I try to run the following code: `pip install git+https://github.com/cog-imperial/GPdoemd` I receive this error:

`Collecting git+https://github.com/cog-imperial/GPdoemd Cloning https://github.com/cog-imperial/GPdoemd to c:\users\i6817\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-df6ldcn1 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://github.com/cog-imperial/GPdoemd 'C:\Users\I6817\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-df6ldcn1' Check the logs for full command output.`

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You can try this way `It is also possible to clone into/download the GPdoemd git repository and install it using setup.py, but this is not recommended for most users.`

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to find a way to install it as described above

Comment: Do you have `git` installed and available in `$PATH`? Can you clone the repo using `git clone https://github.com/cog-imperial/GPdoemd.git`?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the follow command and it's work for me. I used python 3.8.5 and the Ubuntu OS.

```
python3 -m venv myenv

source myenv/bin/activate

pip install --upgrade pip

pip install wheel

pip install numpy scipy six paramz matplotlib

pip install GPy

pip install git+https://github.com/cog-imperial/GPdoemd
```

The result:

```
(myenv)computer:/test$ python

Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import GPdoemd
>>> GPdoemd.__version__
'1.1'
```

Comment: I managed to run `pip install git+https://github.com/cog-imperial/GPdoemd.git` successfully in a new empty virtualenv even without installing dependencies; `pip` installs them after cloning.